# UWP app not scaling properly when changes size of text from Settings

Tags: uwp, windows-10, font-scaling

I have set font sizes of my labels and text boxes like this `meyHyperlink.FontSize = 24;`
But, when I try to change the size of text from Scale and layout section in Settings -> Display it doesn't affect properly. If I change to 175% and go back to 100%, text are very smaller than it's original loaded size.

What is the reason for this? How can I solve this?

**SCREEN SHOTS**

Loading time 
[image]

125%
[image]

150%
[image]

175%
[image]

100%
[image]

Comment: Could you post some screenshots of what is happening and relevant part of your source code?

Comment: @MartinZikmund Thanks for looking into this. I updated the screen shots with the text scale. Kindly check it.